# Exposing a list of users in Active Directory securely

Tags: active-directory

So I've got an Active Directory environment set up, and it's using ADFS to allow applications outside of my environment to use credentials from my AD.

This is all fine and dandy, but what I need is a way of allowing these external applications to list users within my AD (either everyone, or just in specific subsets).

My limitations are that I need to limit who can see these lists of users (i.e., it needs to be secure: I need to whitelist the applications that have the permission to do this), and the external applications are hosted completely separate to my AD environment (different servers, domains, networks, etc.).  I can configure AD as much as I like, and I have full control over the external applications, but I cannot change the connectivity between the two (I can't set up VPNs, etc.).

I've toyed with the idea of LDAP, but it appears that it is not recommended to expose LDAP publically.  I'm considering LDAPS, but I'm not certain just how recommended that is either.

Does anyone know if there is a standard way of doing this, or have any recommendations?

Comment: Why does an application need a list of users from your AD.  One of the points of using federated credentials is so the app does not need to access the source creds.

Comment: The applications need to know who are potential users, because things can happen to those users before they access the application for the first time.

Comment: The app needs to be redesigned as a federated app.  Federated apps do not need to enumerate the directory to function.  As users log in the app should then maintain it's own ID to map to that particular login (if something is not available in the claim)

Comment: I'm afraid we can't do that.  The relationship between the apps can't change - the application needs to know the list of users before the users log in.

Answer (score -1):

One approach could be to set up a RODC on its own perimeter (if you haven't got one already), then allow LDAP queries there over LDAPS (636/tcp) from external networks using a dedicated user account (with nothing but Domain User access) for queries. You would be of course exposing a whole lot of your AD infrastructure just for one application to check something.

Or you could schedule an automatically generated report of specific user accounts along with their required attributes and SFTP that wherever the information is required and expose close to none of anything that's not absolutely required.

There's no simple answer for a scenario like this, you need to balance out the usability vs security carefully.

Comment: RODCs simply allow you to export a limited set of attributes in case the device is physically stolen.  This would do very little in the sense of security for someone enumerating the domain.